# How to detect room borders with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to clear a floor plan and detect walls. I found this solution but it is quite difficult understand the code. 
Specially this line (how does it remove texts and others objects inside rooms?)

```
DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .2}]];
```

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhl7.jpg"]
nsc = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .2}]];
m = MorphologicalTransform[nsc, {"Min", "Max"}]
```

How can I do the same with OpenCV?

Comment: what do you mean with "no code"? there is plenty of code in the answers to that question. how you can do the same in OpenCV? You learn image-processing and how to use OpenCV using the countless books and tutorials available. One day you will have enough knowledge to implement a solution.

Comment: My bad, I'l correct it. I mainly do not understand this line
DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .2}]]

Comment: what's there not to understand? this line binarizes img and then deletes small components.

Comment: How I can do it with OpenCV (how does it remove texts and other objects inside rooms? and filter only surrounding walls)

Comment: Open a web browser. Enter www.google.com. Search "DeleteSmallComponents". Click the first hit, read a few lines of the Mathematica documentation. Then search the web for "connected component" read a few links. Then search "connected component OpenCV"... come on it's not that hard is it?

Comment: you get a boost here, but you should always do a minimum of research befor you post a question. if someone asks me what a function does and I enter the function name into google and the first hit is the documentation of that function that describes what the function does, that person appears lazy and disrespectful to me. you should always value volunteers' time by reducing their effort to help you to an absolute minimum. and image-processing wise the best boost you can get is to know the fundamentals well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In opencv there is slightly different approach to process images. In order to do some calculation you have to think in more low-level way. By low-level I mean thinking in basic image processing operations.

For example, line you showed:

```
DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .2}]];
```

Could be expressed in opencv by algorithm:

1. binarize image
2. morphological open/close or simple dilation/erosion (based on what is color of objects and background):

   ```
   cv::threshold(img, img, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
   cv::dilate(img, img, cv::Mat());
   cv::dilate(img, img, cv::Mat());
   ```

[image]

Further you can implement your own distance transformation, or use for example hit-and-miss routine (which as being basic is implemented in opencv) to detect corners:

```
cv::Mat kernel = (cv::Mat_<int>(7, 7) <<
    0, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,
    -1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,
    -1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,
    -1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
    -1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
    -1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0);
cv::Mat left_down,left_up,right_down,right_up;
cv::morphologyEx(img, left_down, cv::MORPH_HITMISS, kernel);
cv::flip(kernel, kernel, 1);
cv::morphologyEx(img, right_down, cv::MORPH_HITMISS, kernel);
cv::flip(kernel, kernel, 0);
cv::morphologyEx(img, right_up, cv::MORPH_HITMISS, kernel);
cv::flip(kernel, kernel, 1);
cv::morphologyEx(img, left_up, cv::MORPH_HITMISS, kernel);
```

and then you will have picture like this:

[image: left_down corners]
One more picture with bigger dots (after single dilation):

[image]
Finally you can process coordinates of corners found to determine rooms.

EDIT: for images with "double wall lines" like: 
[image]

We have to "merge" double wall lines first, so code will be visible like this:

```
 cv::threshold(img, img, 220, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
 cv::dilate(img, img, cv::Mat()); //small object textures
 cv::erode(img, img, cv::getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5)),cv::Point(-1,-1),2);
 cv::dilate(img, img, cv::getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 3);
```

And result image:

[image]

Sadly, if image properties change you will have to slightly change algorithm parameters. There is posibility to provide general solution, but you have to determine most of possible variants of problem and it will be more complex.

Comment: working properly for that image. unfortunately not working for this random floor plan in google search (or similar) http://cdn.freshome.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/floor-plan_s.jpg  , any idea?

Comment: the documentation and function name DeleteSmallComponents indicates that they actually do a component analysis and then delete blobls with small area. your morphological approach approach just deletes thin stuff. you also suggested to open/close but only dilated in your example. I find that confusing.

Comment: @jonarya you will not get a solution here that works for every image. that's why it is important to know image-processing. only then you can understand, modify and apply algorithms efficiently to your problems. do yourself a favour and read a few books.

Comment: @Piglet i did proper open/close in edit. I suggested that solution, because in my opinion it suits better simple case jonarya provided. And about solution for every image i agree with you - solution has to be fitted with problem.